# How to display GridView inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-cardview

I wish to display albums in grid with Album art, album name and number of songs.

These are my xml layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/metalList">


<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

and for individual items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/metalList"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:elevation="4dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/albumart"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/musicicon"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/album_name"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/metalTextB"
                android:layout_below="@id/albumart"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="Album"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songs_num"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/album_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/metalTextS"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="artist"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the codes for the Fragment and Activity

**Albums.java**
    public class Albums extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {

```
AlbumsAdapter mAdapter;

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

private int position;

public static Albums newInstance(int position) {
    Albums f = new Albums();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.albums, container, false);
    GridView grid = (GridView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid);
    mAdapter = new AlbumsAdapter(getActivity(), null);
    grid.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return myFragmentView;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}


static final String[] ALBUM_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = { MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST};



public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String select = null;
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,ALBUM_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, null);
}



public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}



public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}

public class AlbumsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public AlbumsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ImageView albumArt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.albumart);
    albumArt.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    if(img !=null)
        albumArt.setImageBitmap(img);
    else{
        Bitmap bit = getDefaultAlbumArt(context);
        albumArt.setImageBitmap(bit);
    }

    TextView albumTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_name);
    albumTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));

    TextView artistName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songs_num);
    artistName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST)));

}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    return view;
}
public Bitmap getDefaultAlbumArt(Context context) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    try {
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.musicicon, options);
    } catch (Error ee) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bm;
}
```

}

**AlbumsAdapter.java**
    public class AlbumsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public AlbumsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ImageView albumArt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.albumart);
    albumArt.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    if(img !=null)
        albumArt.setImageBitmap(img);
    else{
        Bitmap bit = getDefaultAlbumArt(context);
        albumArt.setImageBitmap(bit);
    }

    TextView albumTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_name);
    albumTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));

    TextView artistName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songs_num);
    artistName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST)));

}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    return view;
}
public Bitmap getDefaultAlbumArt(Context context) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    try {
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.musicicon, options);
    } catch (Error ee) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bm;
}
```

}

I am getting a "java.lang.NullPointerException" with these codes.

Comment: How did you bind the two? Where is your adapter?

Comment: Please tell me how to make one. Adapters are really confusing me. So far I have only implemented array adapters.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: @iturki I have edited the post with adapter code..PLease have a look..It is returning null pointer exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please change same as below ?

```
View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.albums, container, false);
GridView grid = (GridView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid);
```

to

```
View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.albums, container, false);
GridView grid = (GridView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
```

**Reason:**

In fragment you have to bind child view to fragment view.

**Done**

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you please tell my, if I wish to create a onClickListener method, where should I put it and how do I display all the songs in album on clicking the grid item?

Comment: @AritraBhattacharyya, you have to take onItemClickListener for Gridview's item selection, you can do it either on onCreateView() or onActivityCreated(). onCreateView & onActivityCreated both are part of fragment's life cycle.

Comment: Thanks again. But can you tell me what should I do to extract all the songs of the particular album?

Comment: @AritraBhattacharyya, can you please let me know what you want to do on grid view?

Comment: Its a grid of albums of music files. As I click on each grid item, I want it do display all the tracks and details of the album in a separate window. Just like any normal music player.

Comment: @AritraBhattacharyya, implements gridview.setonItemClickListener() and pass third argument (position) you click on item. then you can do as per position

Comment: Thanks. Could you please look into this question as well   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892982/how-do-i-add-song-title-and-album-art-in-a-listview-and-launch-a-player-on-click

Comment: @HirenPatel ,Can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957819/gridview-and-it-is-images-are-not-automatically-fit-for-all-the-screen-sizes-in